# S/MIME fails utterly with OWA on IE11

Tags: outlook, outlook-web-app, smime

I have OWA set up on IE11 with S/MIME. At some point recently things went sideways and now things are broken:

1. I cannot view any digitally signed email (including sent items signed by me). The emails open. The sender and recipients all show up. The body of the email is simply blank. This happens with the preview pane on the main window as well as when you open the email in a new window.  No console errors show up when I try to view these emails (when I uninstall S/MIME I can see the emails in their entirety. Obviously I also get an error saying that the digital signature cannot be validated).
2. I cannot send ANY emails (signed or otherwise). It allows me to craft the email as normal but when I hit "send" nothing happens (without S/MIME I can send emails without issue). I receive the following javascript error in the console:

   > SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'replace' of undefined or null reference
   >   fedtsmime.js (1,72117)
3. When crafting a new email, for some crazy reason my personalized signature (the auto-appended variety in the body of the email) doesn't show up (without S/MIME it shows up).

Information that may help inform the problem:

1. I have cleared ALL historical data, ALL form data, and reset my SSL state in IE11. Nothing changed.
2. I have traced the certificate chain all the way up and they are all properly located in the "local machine" trust store.
3. THIS USED TO WORK. A few weeks back I didn't have any issues. Now suddenly it all fails. That implies perhaps that something expired? But I checked the full chain and it seems OK.
4. I did not bother trying to work with encrypting emails since I cannot send any emails whatsoever.
5. My certificates are being accessed via Smart Card. I am using ActivClient.
6. I made sure TLS is enabled and SSL 2.0 is disabled.

Answer (score 2):

We found a mitigation that lets you **send & receive encrypted and unencrypted email**, but will not let you open attachments:

1. Open the **Tools** menu in IE11 (the settings cog)
2. Under the **Security** tab, click **Trusted Sites**
3. Add `https://*.mail.mil` as a trusted site.

This should allow you to do most of what is needed. My understanding is that the null reference you're seeing is probably pointing towards an ActiveX control that is disabled in the stricter browsing modes.

We also had **Enable enhanced protected mode** turned on in the **Advanced>Security** section, but that did not seem to have an effect. We are also launching IE from `Program Files (x86)` instead, to try and launch in 32-bit mode, but we do not know if that has an effect.

EDIT: I found a source elsewhere that provided another helpful workaround. In addition to the above, you can view the list of already-attached attachments:

1. Add some attachments
2. Save the email as a draft. You may want to wait for the attachments to load (you'll have to guess at the upload time; but there may be some indication on the saving button)
3. Close the email edit window
4. Reopen the email edit window from the saved drafts page. You should see your attachments.

---

*Disclaimer: I work for Microsoft.*

Answer (score 1):

I have the blank email body symptom also.  I solved it by running OWA in a Chrome Incognito window.  Problem gone.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a super old thread but I've recently come across this problem with IE11 and was racking my brain all weekend over it.

We already know the SMIME controls don't work on Microsoft Edge, but should work in Internet Explorer (just in case new readers are looking at this thread).  The one setting that needs to be changed is the compatibility view settings.

Once you add mail.mil to the compatibility view list, your SMIME control will work again.

For those that don't know how to get there:

1. Click on the GEAR symbol in the upper right corner of your Internet Explorer window and then select COMPATIBILITY VIEW SETTINGS.
2. When the pop-up windows appears, add mail.mil to the list and then
   test it again.

I guess it wouldn't hurt to also add https://*.mail.mil to the list of TRUSTED SITES as well.

Good luck to those who are searching the internet and finding this thread. ;)

Comment: Maybe separate paragraphs, remove some introduction and personal feelings. Any word not belonging to the answer just causes false hits for people looking for an answer. For example you answer is not about "good luck" and not about "brain"...

Answer (score 0):

For IE11:

Once you do all the steps shared here, and elsewhere, you should see the email in the preview pane with the To/From info and blank body (no s/mime errors).

Simply double-click the message to open it within it's own new window to load and view the content.